# How to prove that addition is commutative for conatural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq, coinductive-type

I have defined the conatural numbers, bisimulation (extensional equality?) and addition as follows,

```
CoInductive CoNat :=
| Z : CoNat
| S : CoNat -> CoNat.

CoInductive bisimilar : CoNat -> CoNat -> Prop :=
| bisimilar_Z: bisimilar Z Z
| bisimilar_S: forall n m, bisimilar m n ->  bisimilar (S m) (S n).

CoFixpoint coadd (m : CoNat) (n : CoNat) :=
  match m with
  | Z => n
  | S m' => S (coadd m' n)
  end.
```

and the following to  help with reducing expressions

```
Definition evalCoNat (n : CoNat) :=
  match n with
  | Z => Z
  | S n => S n
  end.

Lemma evalCoNat_eq : forall n : CoNat,  n = evalCoNat n.
```

To get myself acquainted with coinduction I was trying to prove the following

```
Lemma bisimilar_coadd_comm: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar (coadd m n) (coadd n m).
```

I assumed that proving commutativity was analogous to proving commutativity of addition for natural numbers, so I proved the following,

```
Lemma bisim_reflexive: forall n: CoNat, bisimilar n n.
Lemma bisim_symmetric: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar m n -> bisimilar n m.
Lemma bisim_transitive: forall m n o : CoNat, bisimilar m n -> bisimilar n o -> bisimilar m o.

Lemma bisimilar_coadd_n_Z: forall n,  bisimilar (coadd n Z) n.
Lemma bisimilar_coadd_Z_n: forall n,  bisimilar (coadd Z n) n.
Lemma bisimilar_m_Sn: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar (S (coadd m n)) (coadd m (S n)).
```

Now I've attempted to prove `bisimilar_coadd_comm` but I'm getting an error saying I'm not in guarded form.

```
Lemma bisimilar_coadd_comm: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar (coadd m n) (coadd n m).
Proof.  
  cofix CIH.
  intros m n.
  destruct m.
  (* bisimilar (coadd Z n) (coadd n Z) *)
  - rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n := coadd Z n). simpl.
    destruct n.
    + rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n := coadd Z Z). simpl.
      apply bisimilar_Z.
    + apply bisim_symmetric. apply  bisimilar_coadd_n_Z.
  (* bisimilar (coadd (S m) n) (coadd n (S m)) *)
  - rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n := coadd (S m) n).
    simpl.
    apply bisim_transitive with (n := S (coadd n m)).
    + apply bisimilar_S. apply CIH.
    + apply bisimilar_m_Sn.
Qed.
```

After reading Chapter 5 of Adam's Chipala's "Certified Programming with Dependent Types", I (kind of) understood how coinductive proofs correspond to corecursive functions and that "a corecursive call must be a direct argument to a constructor, only inside of other constructor calls or fun or match expressions".

After looking at my error again I find the proof object breaking this condition is

```
bisim_transitive 
    (S (coadd c n)) m
    (S (coadd n c)) n 
    (coadd n (S c)) o 
    (bisimilar_S (coadd n c) (coadd c n) (bisimilar_coadd_comm c n))
    (bisimilar_m_Sn n c)
:
    bisimilar (evalCoNat (coadd (S c) n)) (coadd n (S c))
```

So my guess is that the guardedness condition is not met as `bisimilar_S` is under `bisim_transitive`? But I don't know how I could prove this without using the transitive property. Would I need an extra lemma? Is there a simple trick? Is there a some rule of thumb?

My current understanding of coinduction after reading a bit of Davide Sangiorgi's "An introduction to bisimulation and coinduction" is that I would need to prove is that properties are maintained backwards. That is if a property $P$ for a conclusion is true then the property $P$ is also true for the premises.

But maybe my understanding isn't right...

If possible I would like an informal proof, and then a proof in Coq.
Moreover, a correction if I'm misunderstanding coinduction.

Edit: Renamed the coinduction hypothesis from `bisimilar_coadd_comm` to `CIH` in `bisimilar_coadd_comm`

Answer (score 6):

You just have to be a bit smarter about the definition of `coadd` so that it consumes both arguments.

```ml
CoInductive CoNat :=
| Z : CoNat
| S : CoNat -> CoNat.

CoInductive bisimilar : CoNat -> CoNat -> Prop :=
| bisimilar_Z: bisimilar Z Z
| bisimilar_S: forall n m, bisimilar m n ->  bisimilar (S m) (S n).

CoFixpoint coadd (m : CoNat) (n : CoNat) :=
  match m, n with
  |   Z,   Z => Z
  |   Z, S n => S n
  | S m,   Z => S m
  | S m, S n => S (S (coadd m n))
  end.

Definition evalCoNat (n : CoNat) :=
  match n with
  | Z => Z
  | S n => S n
  end.

Lemma bisim_reflexive: forall n: CoNat, bisimilar n n.
Proof.
  cofix CIH.
  intros [|n] ; now constructor.
Qed.

Lemma evalCoNat_eq : forall n : CoNat,  n = evalCoNat n.
Proof.
  intros [|n] ; reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma bisimilar_coadd_comm:
  forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar (coadd m n) (coadd n m).
Proof.
  cofix CIH.
  intros m n.
  destruct m ; destruct n.
  - rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd Z Z)).
    constructor.
  - rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd Z (S n))).
    rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd (S n) Z)).
    constructor.
    apply bisim_reflexive.
  - rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd (S m) Z)).
    rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd Z (S m))).
    constructor.
    apply bisim_reflexive.
  - rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd (S m) (S n))).
    rewrite (evalCoNat_eq (coadd (S n) (S m))).
    simpl.
    apply bisimilar_S.
    now apply bisimilar_S.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess this definition of `coadd` is what is standard?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Yours is more like concatenation and mine is more like interweaving. Mine happens to be better suited for proving commutativity.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the techniques described in Nils Anders Danielsson's [Beating the Productivity Checker Using Embedded Languages](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Enad/publications/danielsson-productivity.html).

I've used them in the [Agda standard library](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Codata.Guarded.Stream.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.html#3871) and successfully deployed the resulting DSL to prove lemmas involving transitivity (e.g. [this one](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Codata.Guarded.Stream.Properties.html#4627)) in a guarded manner.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try looking into this technique.

Answer (score 2):

[Andrej Bauer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/169/andrej-bauer) has introduced a smarter definition of `coadd` and has proven that it is commutative.

However, I would like to show that we can prove commutativity without updating the definition of `coadd`.

The full proof can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ConDai/37436eddfe863861e95a8bd8066a2a15)

The proof involves natural numbers so I will update my notation to hopefully avoid confusion.

For example, `S` is replaced with `CoS` to avoid confusion with the successor constructor `S` for natural numbers.

Futhermore, I will be using `n` and `m` for `CoNat` and `N` for `nat`

The definitions from my question are updated as follows (note that only the notation has changed)

```
CoInductive CoNat :=
| CoZ : CoNat
| CoS : CoNat -> CoNat.

CoInductive bisimilar : CoNat -> CoNat -> Prop :=
| bisimilar_CoZ: bisimilar CoZ CoZ
| bisimilar_CoS: forall n m, bisimilar m n ->  bisimilar (CoS m) (CoS n).

Definition evalCoNat (n : CoNat) :=
  match n with
  | CoZ => CoZ
  | CoS n => CoS n
  end.

CoFixpoint coadd (m : CoNat) (n : CoNat) :=
  match m with
  | CoZ => n
  | CoS m' => CoS (coadd m' n)
  end.
```

from these definitions you are able to prove the following

```
bisim_reflexive: forall n: CoNat, bisimilar n n
bisim_symmetric: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar m n -> bisimilar n m

(* These helped when rewriting *)
coadd_eq_CoZ : forall n, n = coadd CoZ n.
coadd_eq_CoS: forall m n, CoS (coadd m n) = coadd (CoS m) n.

bisimilar_coadd_n_CoZ: forall n, bisimilar (coadd n CoZ) n.
```

Now the trick I found was to introduce

```
Fixpoint succN (N: nat) (n : CoNat) :=
  match N with
  | O => n
  | S N' =>  CoS (succN N' n) 
  end.
```

If we are able to prove a more general lemma

```
Lemma bisimilar_m_succN_n_eq_n_succN_m:
  forall (m n : CoNat) (N : nat), bisimilar (coadd m (succN N n)) (coadd n (succN N m)).
```

then we can prove commutativity as it is a specific case of the lemma above, namely when `N = 0`. That proof is as follows,

```
Lemma bisimilar_coadd_comm: forall m n : CoNat, bisimilar (coadd m n) (coadd n m).
Proof.
  intros m n.
  specialize bisimilar_m_succN_n_eq_n_succN_m with (n:= n) (m:=m) (N:= O).
  auto.
Qed.
```

Before proving `bisimilar_m_succN_n_eq_n_succN_m` we need some auxilliary lemmas

```
(*  succN_eq_O and succN_eq_S helped when rewriting *)
Lemma succN_eq_O: forall n, n = succN O n.
Proof. intros n. reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma succN_eq_S: forall N n, CoS (succN N n) = succN (S N) n. 
Proof. intros N n. reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma succ_N_Cos_n_eq_succN_SN_n: forall N n,  succN N (CoS n) = succN (S N) n.
Proof.
  simpl.
  intros N n.
  induction N.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHN. reflexivity.
  Qed.
```

Now we have everything we need to prove `bisimilar_m_succN_n_eq_n_succN_m`

```
Lemma bisimilar_m_succN_n_eq_n_succN_m:
  forall (m n : CoNat) (N : nat), bisimilar (coadd m (succN N n)) (coadd n (succN N m)).
Proof. 
  cofix CIH.
  intros m n N.
  destruct N; destruct m; destruct n.
  - simpl. apply bisim_reflexive.
  - simpl. 
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd CoZ (CoS n)).  simpl.
    apply bisim_symmetric. apply bisimilar_coadd_n_CoZ.
  - simpl.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd CoZ (CoS m)).  simpl.
    apply bisimilar_coadd_n_CoZ.
  - simpl.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd (CoS m) (CoS n)). simpl.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd (CoS n) (CoS m)). simpl.
    apply bisimilar_CoS.
    specialize CIH with (n:= n) (m:=m) (N:= S O).
    simpl in CIH.
    apply CIH.
  - simpl. apply bisim_reflexive.
  - rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd CoZ (succN (S N) (CoS n))).
    simpl (evalCoNat (coadd CoZ _)).
    rewrite succ_N_Cos_n_eq_succN_SN_n.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd (CoS n) (succN (S N) CoZ)).
    simpl (evalCoNat (coadd (CoS n) _)).
    apply bisimilar_CoS.
    rewrite succN_eq_S.
    rewrite coadd_eq_CoZ with (n:= succN (S N) n).
    apply CIH.
  - rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd CoZ _).
    simpl (evalCoNat (coadd CoZ _)).
    rewrite succ_N_Cos_n_eq_succN_SN_n.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd _ _).
    simpl (evalCoNat (coadd (CoS m) (succN (S N) CoZ))).
    apply bisimilar_CoS.
    rewrite succN_eq_S.
    rewrite coadd_eq_CoZ with (n:= succN (S N) m).
    apply CIH.
  - rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd (CoS m) (succN (S N) (CoS n))). simpl.
    rewrite evalCoNat_eq with (n:= coadd (CoS n) (CoS (succN N (CoS m)))). simpl.
    apply bisimilar_CoS.
    rewrite succ_N_Cos_n_eq_succN_SN_n.
    rewrite succ_N_Cos_n_eq_succN_SN_n.
    rewrite succN_eq_S.
    rewrite succN_eq_S.
    apply CIH.
Qed
```

I understand the names for lemmas and proofs are far from elegant.  Any improvements will be appreciated!

Comment: I wonder how hard it is to prove that the two definitions of `coadd` coincide, as that may be a useful technique to have at hand: use whichever seesm most appropriate in a given situation.

Comment: I believe that they do coincide. It'll probably give rise to a simpler proof than what I have.

Comment: By the way, the crucial lemma you proved, that's a typical situation one often faces, namely to find a slightly more general statement that does go through in a (co)inductive proof. In this case, one needs to know what is going on when some amount of the second arguments has been consumed, and the answer is "you get a bunch of successors inserted in" – so you need to account for that.

Comment: I would actually expect that showing the two definitions to coincide will be exactly as hard as your proof. That's because mine is very easy, and by The Law of Preservation of Trouble, we won't make trouble go away magically.

Comment: Hmm. Well I guess the only way to be know for certain is by trying.